# What's the best way to group a JSON object by a certain value?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to be able to display data in an React application like so:

```
Today
- Batman entered the watchtower at 10:30am
- Batman entered the watchtower at 10:15am
- Wonder Woman entered the watchtower at 10:00am

Yesterday
- Flash entered the watchtower at 10:30am
- Green Lantern entered the watchtower at 10:15am
- Cyborg entered the watchtower at 10:00am

9th August 2018
- Aquaman entered the watchtower at 10:30am
```

The data being sent to me is an <strike>JSON</strike> Array of objects:

```
[{
    "name": "Batman",
    "secret_identity": "Bruce Wayne",
    "timestamp": "1533983400" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:30am
},
{
    "name": "Superman",
    "secret_identity": "Clark Kent",
    "timestamp": "1533982500" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:15am
},
{
    "name": "Wonder Woman",
    "secret_identity": "Diana Prince",
    "timestamp": "1533981600" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:00am
},
{
    "name": "Flash",
    "secret_identity": "Wally West",
    "timestamp": "1533897000" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:30am
},
{
    "name": "Green Lantern",
    "secret_identity": "Hal Jordan",
    "timestamp": "1533896100" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:15am
},
{
    "name": "Cyborg",
    "secret_identity": "Victor Stone",
    "timestamp": "1533895800" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:00am
},
{
    "name": "Aquaman",
    "secret_identity": "Arthur Curry",
    "timestamp": "1533810600" // Epoch timestamp equating to 9th August 2018 at 10:30am
}]
```

I am not sure what's the best way to use this <strike>JSON</strike> Array to render the data in the way that I need. I thought I may need to process the data further in a new object like below but am not sure the best way to do so.

```
[{
    "11-August-2018" : [{
        "name": "Batman",
        "secret_identity": "Bruce Wayne",
        "timestamp": "1533983400" // 11th August 2018 at 10:30am
    },
    {
        "name": "Superman",
        "secret_identity": "Clark Kent",
        "timestamp": "1533982500" // 11th August 2018 at 10:15am
    },
    {
        "name": "Wonder Woman",
        "secret_identity": "Diana Prince",
        "timestamp": "1533981600" // 11th August 2018 at 10:00am
    }],
    "10-August-2018" : [{
        "name": "Flash",
        "secret_identity": "Wally West",
        "timestamp": "1533897000" // 10th August 2018 at 10:30am
    },
    {
        "name": "Green Lantern",
        "secret_identity": "Hal Jordan",
        "timestamp": "1533896100" // 10th August 2018 at 10:15am
    },
    {
        "name": "Cyborg",
        "secret_identity": "Victor Stone",
        "timestamp": "1533895800" // 10th August 2018 at 10:00am
    }],
    "09-August-2018" : [{
        "name": "Aquaman",
        "secret_identity": "Arthur Curry",
        "timestamp": "1533810600" // 9th August 2018 at 10:30am
    }]
}]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a *JSON object*. If it's JSON, it's **always** a `string`, if it's an `object`, it's Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting, mapping, reducing. Gotta love [es2018](http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/)

```js
(d => {
  // a few utility methods
  const dateFromEpoch = epochStr => new Date(new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(+epochStr));
  const padLeft = n => `${n}`.padStart(2, "0");
  const removeTime = dateTime => new Date(dateTime.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
  const getDateLabel = dateTime => {
    const now = removeTime(new Date());
    const plainDate = removeTime(dateTime);
    const dayDiff = Math.abs(Math.round(((plainDate - now) / 3600000) / 24));
    return dayDiff < 1 ?
      "Today" :
       dayDiff === 1 ?
       "Yesterday" :
       `${dayDiff} Days ago`;
  };

  const heroicData = getHeroicData()
    .sort((a, b) => +a.timestamp < +b.timestamp) // sort descending
    .reduce(heroicReducer, {});                  // create reshuffled object

  // the heroic entry points
  d.querySelector("#raw").textContent = JSON.stringify(heroicData, null, " ");

  // create html output using a reducer
  d.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = Object.keys(heroicData)
    .reduce((reduced, day) =>
      reduced.concat(`
        <b>${day}</b>
        <ul>
          ${heroicData[day].map(visit => `<li>${visit}</li>`).join("")}
        </ul>`), [])
    .join("");

  function heroicReducer(reduced, heroicVisit) {
    const dateTime = dateFromEpoch(heroicVisit.timestamp);
    const reportKey = getDateLabel(dateTime);
    const reportString = `<heroe>${
      heroicVisit.name}</heroe> entered the watchtower at ${
         padLeft(dateTime.getHours())}:${
          padLeft(dateTime.getMinutes())}`;
    if (reduced[reportKey]) {
      reduced[reportKey].push(reportString)
    } else {
      reduced[reportKey] = [reportString];
    }
    return reduced;
  }

  function getHeroicData() {
    return [{
        "name": "Batman",
        "secret_identity": "Bruce Wayne",
        "timestamp": "1533983400"
      },
      {
        "name": "Superman",
        "secret_identity": "Clark Kent",
        "timestamp": "1533982500"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wonder Woman",
        "secret_identity": "Diana Prince",
        "timestamp": "1533981600"
      },
      {
        "name": "Flash",
        "secret_identity": "Wally West",
        "timestamp": "1533897000"
      },
      {
        "name": "Green Lantern",
        "secret_identity": "Hal Jordan",
        "timestamp": "1533896100"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cyborg",
        "secret_identity": "Victor Stone",
        "timestamp": "1533895800"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aquaman",
        "secret_identity": "Arthur Curry",
        "timestamp": "1533810600"
      }
    ];
  }
})(document);
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
  margin: 3em;
}

heroe {
  color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<pre id="raw"></pre>
<h3>**Reduced to output</h3>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! I have got to try this!

Comment: Feel free to play around with it @ http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/tLoc387j/

Comment: Marked as accepted for completeness but @max-sinev answer also works and is beautiflly simple. Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can group data with `reduce` function for example, also you can format date object by yourself or if you need some complex formatting in future you can use **moment.js** library(render "today", "yesterday", "th", "rd" etc). So I don't map month names and used just UTC in my example:

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "Batman",
    "secret_identity": "Bruce Wayne",
    "timestamp": "1533983400" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:30am
},
{
    "name": "Superman",
    "secret_identity": "Clark Kent",
    "timestamp": "1533982500" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:15am
},
{
    "name": "Wonder Woman",
    "secret_identity": "Diana Prince",
    "timestamp": "1533981600" // Epoch timestamp equating to 11th August 2018 at 10:00am
},
{
    "name": "Flash",
    "secret_identity": "Wally West",
    "timestamp": "1533897000" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:30am
},
{
    "name": "Green Lantern",
    "secret_identity": "Hal Jordan",
    "timestamp": "1533896100" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:15am
},
{
    "name": "Cyborg",
    "secret_identity": "Victor Stone",
    "timestamp": "1533895800" // Epoch timestamp equating to 10th August 2018 at 10:00am
},
{
    "name": "Aquaman",
    "secret_identity": "Arthur Curry",
    "timestamp": "1533810600" // Epoch timestamp equating to 9th August 2018 at 10:30am
}]

let result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let date = new Date(item.timestamp*1000);
    let key = `${date.getUTCDate()}-${date.getUTCMonth()+1}-${date.getUTCFullYear()}`;
    if (!acc[key]) {
        acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(item);
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two smaller problems that you are trying to solve here:

- Mapping epoch to date,
- Grouping events by date

I'll use utility library`ramda` to simplify the answer, but you could implement your own `groupBy` function if you wanted to.

Possible solution:

```
const epochToDate = epoch => {
  const date = new Date(epoch)
  return `${date.getDate()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getFullYear()}`
}
const groupedJson = R.groupBy(
  event => epochToDate(parseInt(event.timestamp, 10)),
  rawJson
)
```

You can play with it in [ramda repl](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?const%20rawJson%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Batman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Bruce%20Wayne%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533983400%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2011th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A30am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Superman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Clark%20Kent%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533982500%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2011th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A15am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Wonder%20Woman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Diana%20Prince%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533981600%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2011th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A00am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Flash%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Wally%20West%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533897000%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2010th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A30am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Green%20Lantern%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Hal%20Jordan%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533896100%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2010th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A15am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Cyborg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Victor%20Stone%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533895800%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%2010th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A00am%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Aquaman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22secret_identity%22%3A%20%22Arthur%20Curry%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22timestamp%22%3A%20%221533810600%22%20%2F%2F%20Epoch%20timestamp%20equating%20to%209th%20August%202018%20at%2010%3A30am%0A%7D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20epochToDate%20%3D%20epoch%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20date%20%3D%20new%20Date%28epoch%29%0A%20%20return%20%60%24%7Bdate.getDate%28%29%7D-%24%7Bdate.getMonth%28%29%20%2B%201%7D-%24%7Bdate.getFullYear%28%29%7D%60%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20groupedJson%20%3D%20R.groupBy%28%0A%20%20event%20%3D%3E%20epochToDate%28parseInt%28event.timestamp%2C%2010%29%29%2C%0A%20%20rawJson%0A%29%0A%0AgroupedJson).

Answer (score 0):

u have to import the json file to your react application like this

```
import data from './data.json'

this.data = data
```

and just work with it like any other object

Answer (score 0):

```
    outJSON= [ {team: "TeamA",name: "Ahmed",field3:"val3"}, {team: "TeamB",name: "Ahmed",field3:"val43"}, {team: "TeamA",name: "Ahmed",field3:"val55"} ]

var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
var groubedByTeam=groupBy(outJSON, 'team')
console.log(groubedByTeam);
```